# speed python script on command line vs launched in IDLE shell

Tags: command-line, python, speed

I noticed several times that a simple python script (with some straightforward algebraic computation in a loop) runs considerably faster (up to a factor 6) when launched on a shell command line as compared to a run via IDLE's shell. There is nothing fancy going on in the script. I only print a loop variable to visually follow progress in the loop.

Surely just this print statement cannot be the reason for the speed loss in IDLE, or can it ?

Can someone explain me why this is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the print statement really is the main cause of slow-down within idle. The stdout and stderr streams are captured by IDLE, and a whole bunch of Tk commands are executed to render the text appropriately. Removing your output to stdout should speed things up again.

See the [idlelib.PyShell](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b3168643677b/Lib/idlelib/PyShell.py#l871), [idlelib.OutputWindow](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b3168643677b/Lib/idlelib/OutputWindow.py#l37), and [idlelib.EditorWindow](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b3168643677b/Lib/idlelib/EditorWindow.py#l110) modules for (some of) the extent of the rabbit hole...

I would suggest using the [logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module to record progress; you can then set the logging level to something higher when running in IDLE to avoid output in that condition, or log somewhere other than stdout.

Although I **really** wouldn't recommend it, something like the following probably works *most* of the time if you really want to be able to configure behaviour differently when running under IDLE. Though you really shouldn't :-)

```
import sys

running_under_idle = 'idlelib' in sys.modules
```